# Is there a Python library that can extract motion vectors from H.264 P- and B-frames?

Tags: python, vector, h.264, motion

As the title suggests, I am looking for a Python library that can read an MP4/MKV file and extract the motion vectors for all the macroblocks in each frame.

Are there any Python libraries that can do this?

Comment: nope not AFAIK but you can use the reference decoder and the debug-output to output that info in textformat and parse it using python.

Comment: @FredrikPihl What is this reference decoder you're talking about? I'm on Linux, does it work for Linux as well? Parsing output from an external program is fine for my use case.

Comment: latest version 18.5 can be found @ http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/ And, YES, it works for linux!

Comment: @runeks Did you get this to work?  Do you have any code you'd be willing to share?

Comment: @saulspatz I didn't get far with this, but I did end up with some working code, by patching ffmpeg to print information about macroblocks, and then parsing this output using a Python script. It's not much, but it's better than nothing I guess: https://github.com/runeksvendsen/python-mv